# Kaminari & Rails pagination - undefined method `current_page'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari

I searched and searched, but nothing solved my problem. Here's my controller:

```
def show
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    @topic.posts = @topic.posts.page(params[:page]).per(2) # 2 for debugging
end
```

That functions just fine, because the topic view is reduced to two posts. However, when I add this to show.html.erb:

```
<%= paginate @topic.posts %>
```

I'm given this error:

```
undefined method `current_page' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x69041c9b2d58>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try with:

```
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @topic.posts.page(params[:page]).per(2)
end
```

And then:

```
<%= paginate @posts %>
```

Answer (score 22):

If you get pagination errors in Kaminari like

> undefined method `total_pages'

or

> undefined method `current_page'

it is likely because the AR scope you've passed into `paginate` has not had the `page` method called on it.

Make sure you always call `page` on the scopes you will be passing in to `paginate`!

This also holds true if you have an Array that you have decorated using `Kaminari.paginate_array`

Bad:

```
<% scope = Article.all    # You forgot to call page :(  %>
<%= paginate(scope)       # Undefined methods...        %>
```

Good:

```
<% scope = Article.all.page(params[:page]) %>
<%= paginate(scope) %>
```

Or with a non-AR array of your own...

Bad:

```
<% data = Kaminari.paginate_array(my_array)   # You forgot to call page :(        %>
<%= paginate(data)                            # Undefined methods...     %>
```

Again, this is good:

```
<% data = Kaminari.paginate_array(my_array).page(params[:page]) %>
<%= paginate(data) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago, I had a little problem with kaminari that I solved by using different variable names for each action.

Let's say in the `index` action you call something like:

```
def index
  @topic = Topic.all.page(params[:page])
end
```

The `index` view works fine with `<%= paginate @topic %>` however if you want to use the same variable name in any other action, it throu an error like that.

```
def list
  # don't use @topic again. choose any other variable name here
  @topic_list = Topic.where(...).page(params[:page])
end
```

This worked for me.

Please, give a shot.

Comment: (I know it's old) Any idea on why this could ever happen?