# How to display images using Ruby paginate library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari

I am using [kaminari library](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari), and I want to display users' pictures.

In my UserController, I put

```
def index
    @users = User.order(:name).page params[:page]
end
```

Before, I was accessing the pictures like

```
#users.transitions-enabled
- @users.each do |user|
    - user.pictures.each do |pic|
    .box.panel.panel-default
= link_to (image_tag(pic.image.url(:origin))), user
```

I am now wondering how I can display images by using the following command:

```
<%= paginate @users %>
```

Edit:

Now I changed the code in UserController to

```
@users = User.all
@pictures = @users.pictures.page(params[:page]).per(2)
```

And it is giving me the error

```
undefined method `total_pages' for nil:NilClass
```

I was following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200330/kaminari-rails-pagination-undefined-method-current-page) but I am not sure how I can apply it in my case.

Comment: You can still access the User objects inside @users I suppose, so you can probably keep the same code.

Comment: I am not sure what the resulting html file would look like. If I keep the current html code and put the '<%= paginate @users %>' , the latter does not have any impact.

Comment: paginate method probably only creates a pagination widget... in the view it doesn't impact the content of `@users`. So the image is available inside the `@users` as it would be normally.